# Free OCSP server

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, pki, ocsp

I can't have OCSP with my current OS licensing (2008 R2 Standard) but I need this option. I'm hoping to avoid shelling out an additional $2300.

Are there any open source products that could act as an OCSP responder for my existing internal Microsoft CA? I've seen several options for a complete CA but nothing in the way of MS integration.

Failing something prebuilt what kind of output would I need to pump back from an IIS instance to emulate a success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for "OCSP RFC 2560 OpenSource". There seem to be solutions for this out there. Emulating a success seems to be easy, since OSCP responders can be simulated by replay attacks (according to the [WiKi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol)) The details are outlined in RFC 2560.